# Kotlin - custom date difference in days, weird test behaviour

Tags: kotlin

Consider following function (arguments are Int values following the yyyyMMdd logic, so e.g. 20200131 translates to 2020-Jan-31, it was built based on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference))

```
fun dateDiff(first: Int, second: Int): Long {
    val intToSDF: (date: Int)-> Date? = { date->
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault())
        sdf.parse("$date")
    }
    val diffInMillies: Long = abs(intToSDF(second)!!.time - intToSDF(first)!!.time )
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```

and following test:

```
@Test
fun testDateDiff(){
    assertTrue(dateDiff(20200101, 20200329) == 30L + 29L + 29L)//this is expected
    assertTrue(dateDiff(20200101, 20200330) == 30L + 29L + 29L)//this should fail, but it doesn't
}
```

I cannot figure out why the second assert doesn't fail. Missing time zone handling? Rounding issue? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
Thanks to @Varun example in kotlin playground (link in the comment) I'm onto something. For 20200330 the kotlin playground gives the difference of 7689600000, while when I run locally I get 7686000000 - it's exactly 1h difference, which is probably due to the daylight savings time change (in my location it's 29-Mar-2020 02:00->03:00). What's the best way to account for that? Is  there a way to set the SDF to only use UTC?

Comment: I pasted your code on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ and added the necessary imports. It fails for me, Here is the link to the playground - https://pl.kotl.in/LSHY7kXv5

Answer (score 0):

setting the timezone to GMT solved the issue

```
fun dateDiff(first: Int, second: Int): Long {
    val intToSDF: (date: Int) -> Date? = { date ->
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd z", Locale.getDefault())
        sdf.parse("$date GMT")
    }
    val diffInMillies = abs(intToSDF(second)!!.time - intToSDF(first)!!.time)
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```